# Send files with Connect:Direct from HP NonStop (OSS) to UNIX

Tags: unix, hp-nonstop, connect-direct

Have you have worked with Connect:Direct HP NonStop?
I wish to make the transmission of a file located in 'OSS' HP NonStop to UNIX.

Connect:Direct run it through NDMCOM in GUARDIAN90 but can not interpret my route home from OSS, they will have some idea of missing my script to reconnoitre the route of OSS?

Below I add my script and messages received from the execution of the process.

my process:

```
SEND PROCESS SNODE=TEST.HPTEST SNODEID=(user,passwd)
STEP01 COPY FROM (FILE=/home/sat/origen.txt -
                  SYSOPTS=":datatype=binary:" –
                  PNODE) -
            TO   (FILE='/home/user/destino.txt' -
                  SYSOPTS=":datatype=binary:" -
                 DISP = RPL SNODE)
```

messages:

> **XSMG622I: (RC=8, FDBK="0")
>   An exception response was received during process exec.
>   An exception response was received from the remote node
>   during process execution.
>
> SYSTEM ACTION: The copy step was aborted.
>   RESPONSE:      Check the condition of the copy step
>                  and resubmit the copy step.
>
> **SFLH055I: (RC=8, FDBK="13")
>   source DSN can only be a disk/ spooler file : \DESA.$OSS./home/sat/origen.txt

Comment: thanks for helping with editing

Comment: It looks as though Connect:Direct is trying to resolve the OSS file name using a Guardian volume (\DESA.$OSS). 1) Is OSSFILES set to YES in your NDMINIT file ? 2) Can you set the default volume to (say) /E/DESA rather than $DESA.$OSS anywhere (I know virtually nothing about NDC in the 21st century).